# How to Query "Batch Inserted Neo4j" Graph DB?

Tags: neo4j

By getting idea from [this](http://michaelbloggs.blogspot.de/2013/05/importing-ttl-turtle-ontologies-in-neo4j.html) blog post, I'm implementing DBpedia(.ttl format)- neo4j batch importer. Since, there was no problem with the importing part I couldn't identify how to write queries(ex: check if node with specific property exist in db etc.) for created neo4j database. Tried to use `GraphDatabaService` there but it was impossible and couldn't find related information on [neo4j official website](http://neo4j.com).

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that the web couldn't return you some informations about how to use neo4j and specifically write a query.

The API docs for the GraphDatabaseService are located here :

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html

Moreover, a section in the manual explains you how to use neo4j in embedded mode in Java :

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html

Basically, you need to wrap your operations in transactions :

```
try (Transaction tx = database.beginTx()) {
  database.createNode();
  tx.success();
}
```

Finding a node by label and property is as easy as the previous operation :

```
try (Transaction tx = database.beginTx()) {
  Node user = database.findNode(DynamicLabel.label("User"), "login", "john@doe.com");
  tx.success();
}
```

If you run Neo4j in server mode, you can actually write Cypher queries, pick up a driver for the language of your choice :

http://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/

And a complete Cypher guide is ready for you to read :

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html

You can also follow the free online courses :

http://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-training/

You can also find a huge list of curated Neo4j resources here :

https://github.com/GraphGeeks/awesome-neo4j

Comment: Actually, I was looking for how to query neo4j db which constructed by batch insertion. I couldn't use GraphDatabaseService there, therefore posted this question.

Comment: so you can just start the database and use one of the methods I provided above, moreover you have the neo4j browser, just head to http://localhost:7474